# Replace main image with the clicked one

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a main image, and right underneath it there are 10 smaller ones. When you click on the small picture number 6 for example, the main picture gets replaced by the picture 6, and the heading above it changes from 'Pic1.jpg' to 'Pic6.jpg'. What would be the most efficient way to do this with js?

[image]

Here's what I tried:

```
function changeImage() {
    var m = document.getElementById("mainimgid");
    m.src = document.getElementById(this.id).src;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<img src="img/Pic2.jpg" class="imgmini" id="2" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
```

Comment: share the code you have done so far. one can advise or pick a duplicate from here ... js? onclick attribute or event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onClick event to pass the clicked img info and then change the main element with what you want. Here is my aproach with cute cats:

```js
function changeImage(img) {
document.getElementById("mainimgid").src=img.src;
document.getElementById("text").innerText = img.alt
  
 }
```

```css
img {
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="text">Cute cat</p>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c8/27/78/c827782e12851cd2cf4c5161c4f5445a.jpg" class="imgmini" id="mainimgid" onclick="changeImage(this.src)"></img>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fc/ca/a0/fccaa0fb45fae275fa1b2dd147f1f189.jpg" class="imgmini" id="2" onclick="changeImage(this)" alt="Cute cat1"></img>
<img src="https://filmdaily.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/cute-cat-videos-lede-1300x882.jpg" class="imgmini" id="1" onclick="changeImage(this)" alt="Cute cat2"></img>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I modify this to change h1 text from Pic1 to Pic4 for example?

Comment: In my example you can change the "text" in `document.getElementById("text").innerText = img.alt` to the ID for you h1 element. Then change it according to the picture you pressed. For this example I changed with the value for the alt property in the img tag.

Comment: If you want you can give your images a tittle in the element tag, and then change your h1 to the title inside the pressed img element.

Comment: I tried changing the function to: `function changeImage(img) {
document.getElementById("mainimgid").src=img.src;
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")=img.title;
}` and I gave the image a certain title, but it doesn't work. Edit: I rewrote it and it started working, weirdly. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: That is because when you get elements by tag it return a list of elements and not just one. And also you have to specify what you are changing: `innerText`. So you have to know the desired element index and use it like this `document.getElementsByTagName ("h1")[index].innerText = img.title`

Comment: I recommend using Id instead of tag. Because the index can change if you add or remove other h1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
function changeImage(newMainImage) {
var m = document.getElementById("mainimgid");
m.src = newMainImage.src;
 }
var newImage = document.getElementById("newImageID");
newImage.onclick = () => changeImage(newImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the link to pass the event object,

   ```
    <img src="img/Pic2.jpg" class="imgmini" id="2" onclick="changeImage(event)"></img>
   ```

2.Change the event listener to recieve the passed event object

```
function changeImage(event) {
....
```

}

3. Now you can know which link has triggered the event

   function changeImage(event) {

   ```
        let clickedImage = event.target;
        let clickedImageSrc = clickedImage.getAttribute("src");    
        let m = document.getElementById("mainimgid");
        m.setAttribute("src",clickedImageSrc);
   ```

   }